# Script or method to bulk edit file links within multiple PDFs

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I received a set of project plans consisting of about 500 PDFs in 30 folders. All of these PDFs were originally set up with links based on the filename which previously incorporated the wrong project name. Each file now contains links to all other files with a setup like this:

[image]

The file names used to look like this:

```
Some-Address-Some-Project_designer - Sheet - L200 - PLANS.pdf
```

Now they simply look like this:

```
L200 - PLANS.pdf
```

How can I edit all 500 links in all 500 files to remove this text:

```
Some-Address-Some-Project_designer - Sheet -
```

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro and some skill in using Python, if scripting is an option.

Comment: How were the PDFs produced?  Do you have the source document they were created from?  Normally you should fix the links in the source document, then regenerate the PDF.

Comment: The plans were sent to me. Presumably they were made in Autocad, but there's no way for me to access the originals.